# I am writing a chat app that will have irc style commands. What is the best way to structure the program to process those commands?

Tags: go

I am writing what is essentially a chat program. I want to include some special irc style commands in it and I just can't seem to conceptualize how to structure the program. I'm wondering if people could help me out from a high level perspective. I'm not looking for code, just ideas on how to best proceed.

My best attempt is to have a Command struct like below:

```
type Command struct {
  name     string // the name of the command
  function string // the function that will be called upon match
  help     string // the help message for the command
  regex    string // the regex pattern that will run the command
}
```

and then have a slice of Commands and just iterate over that every time I receive a message from the client. If the received data matches the regex then have the reflect (I think this will work) package call "function". For some reason, I feel like there has to be a better way. I'm learning to code Go on my own and don't have resources available to me to bounce ideas off of. I would very much appreciate your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

In IRC style commands usually a command line looks like this:

```
/cmd [param1] [param2] ... [paramn]
```

When such a command is received, you can split it using [`strings.Split()`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) to get the parts or tokens of the command. By this you will have the first token identifying the command.

You can build a `map[string]Command` map where you map from text commands to their `Command` structure. In this map you can get commands by simply indexing the map, e.g.:

```
cmdMap := make(map[string]Command)
// Populate map

textCmd := "/help"
cmd := cmdMap[textCmd]
```

If you want to have command aliases (e.g. you want `/help` and `/h` and `/?` all to do the same), you can store the list of aliases for each command and when you build the `cmdMap`, also add entries for all aliases to point to the same `Command` structure, in which case you should define it like this:

```
cmdMap := make(map[string]*Command)

helpCmd := &Command{...} // Create help command
cmdMap["/help"] = helpCmd
cmdMap["/h"] = helpCmd
cmdMap["/?"] = helpCmd
```

Note: you could also strip off the leading slash `'/'` and just use the rest of the command (`"help"`, `"h"` and `"?"` in this case) to init your map, it's up to you.

Also you don't have to store the name of the function, functions in Go are values so you can have a function field in your `Command` struct and then you can call that function without reflection. For example:

```
func DoSomething() {
    fmt.Println("Doing something...")
}

var someFv = DoSomething

// And now you can do:
someFv()
```

See [Function types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) and [Function literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals) in the Go Language Specification.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Using a map is an obvious improvement and a great example of exactly what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need to use reflect. You can have the `Command` struct contain a member with a func type.

```
type Command struct {
  name     string // the name of the command
  f        func(string) // the function that will be called upon match
  help     string // the help message for the command
  regex    regexp.Regexp // the regex pattern that will run the command
}

func processMessage(text string){
  for _,cmd := range(allCmds){
    if cmd.regex.MatchString(text){
      cmd.f(text)
      return
    }
  }
  defaultAction(text) //or just add a catch-all with a regex of `.*`
}
```

Then you can add commands with a function of the appropriate signature:

```
cmd := Command{name: "foo",f: func(text string){fmt.Println(text)}}
```

it doesn't have to have exactly that signature. You can have it accept a connection or whatever. You also don't have to inline the function definition, you can reference any function you want that has the appropriate signature.